# daysEl is null Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Yesterday I did countdown timer using JS, but there's 2 problems, console viewing "daysEl is null" in 18 and 30 line, and "redeclaration of const daysEl" in first line. Honestly I don't know what I did wrong. Here's the code:

```
const daysEl = document.getElementById("days");
const hoursEl = document.getElementById("hours");
const minsEl = document.getElementById("mins");
const secondsEl = document.getElementById("seconds");

const webStart = "1 Oct 2021";

function countdown() {
    const webStartDate = new Date(webStart);
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const totalSeconds = (webStartDate - currentDate) / 1000;

    const days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600) % 24;
    const mins = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    const seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds) % 60;

    daysEl.innerHTML = days;
    hoursEl.innerHTML = formatTime(hours);
    minsEl.innerHTML = formatTime(mins);
    secondsEl.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    return time < 10 ? '0${time}' : time;
}

// initial call

countdown();
setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

and here's the structure of the website. It's not fully my code, I'm still refactoring it to look and work good:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Comtatible" concent="IE=edge, chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta name="description" content="Strona poświęcona mojoj działalnośći w    świecie fotografii. Od kilku lat moją pasją i życiem codziennym jest fotografia i na tej stronie chciał bym się nią podzielić z większym gronem odbiorców"/> 
<meta name="keywords" content="pasja, fotografia, zdjęcia, portret, obiektyw, aparat"/>


<title>Patryk Śpiewak Fotografia</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/toggle.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/animate.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/studio.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="Shortcut icon" href="img/iko.png" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gafata|Italianno|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css" type="text/css">
<meta name="author" content="Dawid Girtler">
<link href="jquery.tabSlideOut.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onload="zmienslajd()">
<main>

<header>

<div class="hide">

<div id="toggle">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>

<div id="menu">



<nav class="mobile">

    <li>Portfolio

    <ul>
        <li><a href="prywatne.html">Sesje prywatne</a></li>
        <li><a href="imprezy.html">Imprezy okolicznościowe</a></li>
        <li><a href="koscielne.html">Uroczystości kościelne</a></li>
    </ul>


    </li>
    <li><a href="uslugi.html" class="tilelink">Usługi</a></li>
    <li><a href="studio.html" class="tilelink">Studio</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html" class="tilelink">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="omnie.html" class="tilelink">O mnie</a></li>
    
</nav>


    <div class="center">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PatrykSpiewakFotografia/" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <div class="mediaiko"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></div></a>

        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChbk9ccRM0TDEV_MhoKqhUQ/featured" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <div class="mediaiko"><i class="icon-youtube"></i></div></a>

        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/patrykspiewakfotografia/" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <div class="mediaiko"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></div></a>

        <a href="https://www.messenger.com/t/PatrykSpiewakFotografia?fbclid=IwAR13JuU_-8_Xmq22w2usPNNXGmnRf03cp7GmcEN0FvoOh2IZJ8hO4_actGI" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <div class="mediaiko"><i class="icon-comment-empty"></i></div></a>

        <a href="pobierz.php" class="tilelink">
        <div class="mediaiko"><i class="icon-download" style="color: black"></i></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>

<nav>
<div class="logo"><a href="home.html"><img src="img/home.png" /></a></div>

<div id="menuc">
<ul id="menutest">
    <li onclick ="myFunction()">Portfolio</li>
    <li><a href="uslugi.html">Usługi</a></li>
    <li><a href="studio.html">Studio</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="omnie.html">O mnie</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="menup" class="animated zoomin">
    <li><a href="prywatne.html">Sesje prywatne</a></li>
    <li><a href="imprezy.html">Imprezy okolicznościowe</a></li>
    <li><a href="koscielne.html">Uroczystości kościelne</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

    <div class="social">


      <div class="iko">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PatrykSpiewakFotografia/" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/patrykspiewakfotografia/" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChbk9ccRM0TDEV_MhoKqhUQ/featured" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <i class="icon-youtube"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.messenger.com/t/PatrykSpiewakFotografia" target="_blank" class="tilelink">
        <i class="icon-comment-empty"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="pobierz.php" class="tilelink">
        <i class="icon-download" style="color: black"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Temporary-->
<div class="text">
    <span>Już niedługo... &#128522;</span>
</div>

<div class="countdown-container">
    <div class="countdown-el days-c">
        <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
        <span>Dni</span>
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-el hours-c">
        <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
        <span>Godzin</span>
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-el minutes-c">
        <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
        <span>Minut</span>
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-el seconds-c">
        <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
        <span>Sekund</span>
    </div>
</div>
    <!--Temporary-->
</nav>
</header>
</main>

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>




<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $("#menu").slideToggle();
});
</script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("menup").style.display = "block";

}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function (evt) {
        if(evt.target.tagName != 'LI')
            return;
        $("ul", this).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try moving the four `const` items inside of the function.  If the code is in a STYLE tag in the HEAD tag of the page, the elements won't exist when the script is being run, so daysEl would be null

Comment: The code works fine, I'm guessing that you used this code multiple times in your file and that caused the redeclaration of const daysEl.
Unrelated to the problem you use string literal syntax in a regular string so `'0${time}'` should be actually ``0${time}``.

Comment: @ATD moving `const` inside of the function did nothing, just another redeclaration. If I understand you correctly, my code is not in STYLE tag, it's in a .js file and called in HTML code.

Comment: @SaarDavidson the problem is, I used this code for the first time, it's not being used anywhere else.

Comment: Can you update your question then to show the structure of you page.

Comment: Where do you write the script tag in your HTML file? if it's above the `<body>` tag you should move it just before the closing body tag or use the defer attribute.

Comment: @ATD question updated

Comment: @SaarDavidson I moved it as you said, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you defined the ids wrong in the HTML you should change it like so:

```
<div class="countdown-container">
   <div class="countdown-el days-c">
      <p class="big-text" id="days">0</p>
      <span>Dni</span>
   </div>
   <div class="countdown-el hours-c">
      <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
      <span>Godzin</span>
   </div>
   <div class="countdown-el minutes-c">
      <p class="big-text" id="mins">0</p>
      <span>Minut</span>
   </div>
   <div class="countdown-el seconds-c">
      <p class="big-text" id="seconds">0</p>
      <span>Sekund</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is why people should show HTML in their question.  Given that the HTML wasn't given, I had assumed that the ID itself was not an issue!  Heyho - the js code still needed updating (unless we are currently 8,867 days away from 1 Oct 2021!)

Comment: Yeah, that was a problem, I totally forgot about it, just copied divs, changed classes's names but didn't change id's. Thank you so much.

Comment: Easily done, at least you'll know for next time - check that the ID is there!!!

Comment: @ATD it's 2020 now... everything is possible

Comment: This year can't end soon enough - I'm not sure I'd want a year with 8,800+ days in it :D

Answer (score 1):

@Adam  Saar's suggestion was to EITHER move the tag to the bottom of the page OR add the defer attribute.  I have just created two files:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>Countdown clock</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer>


</script>

<style type="text/css">



</style>
</head>
<body>

<span id="days"></span> days <span id="hours"></span> hours <span id="mins"></span> minutes and <span id="seconds"></span> seconds

</body>
</html>
```

and "script.js" is:

```
const daysEl = document.getElementById("days");
const hoursEl = document.getElementById("hours");
const minsEl = document.getElementById("mins");
const secondsEl = document.getElementById("seconds");

const webStart = "1 Oct 2021";

function countdown() {
    const webStartDate = new Date(webStart);
    var currentDate = new Date();
    const totalSeconds = (webStartDate - currentDate) / 1000;

    const days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / (3600 * 24)); // updated to gets days
    const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600) % 24;
    const mins = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    const seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds) % 60;

    daysEl.innerHTML = days;
    hoursEl.innerHTML = formatTime(hours);
    minsEl.innerHTML = formatTime(mins);
    secondsEl.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    return time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time;  // updated to use backticks instead of quotes
}

// initial call

countdown();
setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

And, this works as I would expect.  I have updated two lines of the script - to get days rather than hours for your "days" element and to use backticks instead of quotes for the template string in `formatTime()`.

So, it is the location of the script that was causing the problem - if you keep it in the `head` tag and use the `defer` attribute as I have done, it works ok.

Comment: using `Math.floor(totalSeconds / (3600 * 24));` got me a right time to desired date. Thank you!